# What's the cheapest way to get from Bucharest Romania to Tbilisi Georgia?

Tags: budget, transportation, eastern-europe, tbilisi, bucharest

A friend of mine in Bucharest with not much cash at hand is wondering how cheaply he could get from there to visit me here in Tbilisi.

I know there are buses from Isanbul to Tbilisi. Maybe there's a bus or train from Bucharest to Istanbul, or maybe changing in Bulgaria would be necessary.

I doubt flying would be cheapest for Tbilisi but you never know.

(We're talking about in the next week, late January 2012 if it makes a difference.)

Comment: The cheapest flight I could find was a two leg flight for 180 Euro.

Answer (score 6):

There is a train from Bucharest to Istanbul every day at 12:20 pm, it merges with the train from Sofia in Eastern Bulgaria and arrives in Istanbul at 7:30 the next morning. [One source](http://www.letsgoistanbul.com/tren.htm) mentions 36 Euros as the price.

There are also buses going directly from Bucharest to Istanbul taking 18 hours.

I am not sure about the prices but I travelled on trains and buses in Romania and Bulgaria last autumn and there were no significant differences between the two. Considering your friend may already take a bus from Istanbul to Georgia, I would recommend the train from Bucharest, personally I would even take the train at least to Ankara and then a bus from there:

Bucharest -> Istanbul by train (36 Euros, 19hr), spending the day in old Istanbul, in the evening taking a ferry (1 Euro, 25min) to the Asian side to board the night train to Ankara (20 Euros, 9hr). From there take a bus to Trabzon in North Eastern Turkey (20 Euros, 13hr). Finally another bus to Tbilisi (14 Euros, 20hr). This may not be the fastest or cheapest but it breaks up a long journey into smaller parts.

Prices and times are from various sources and may be higher now.